# How to check If a string is a word?

Tags: java, android

rookie programmer here.

By word I mean like "apple" is a word but "opple" isn't.

So I wanted to make a really simple app that checked to see what the user inputs is a word or not.

Is there a widget or something I can import to do this?

I haven't seen any documentation on this, but I know spellcheck is built into the phone, so I could use some help.

Comment: Define "word". Precisely. Once you have the definition, you'll almost have the implementation.

Comment: [Android API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html)  I'm not terribly familiar with the API so I can't write up an answer per say, but this should be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a lot way to do this but one way is you basically need to have a list of word in your root directory of your project. After that you user your code to check `String` is part of the word list you have it in your root directory or not.

If you are using java , you may do so as follow `

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Dictionary
{
    private Set<String> wordsSet;

    public Dictionary() throws IOException
    {
        Path path = Paths.get("words.txt");
        byte[] readBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        String wordListContents = new String(readBytes, "UTF-8");
        String[] words = wordListContents.split("\n");
        wordsSet = new HashSet<>();
        Collections.addAll(wordsSet, words);
    }

    public boolean contains(String word)
    {
        return wordsSet.contains(word);
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Android has a spellcheck service you can leverage, so a word list is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

For checking if there's a single word in a string, I'd look for spaces:

```
if (str != null && !str.trim().isEmpty() && str.trim().indexOf(' ') == -1) {
    // it's a single word
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It merely tests if a string is non-null and contains no space char.

Comment: The question was previously unclear - OP edited to clarify that he was asking about spell checking

Comment: Should have waited for clarification, because there was nothing in the original Q that suggested "detect if a string is a single string of chars with no space".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to english language here, there are multiple libraries available if you want to create a dictionary structure like jaazy, or google spell check api.

Although if you don't want all set of some language words and have a small set of words of your own..then

//Use a hashSet keep it static and load all the words in the hashSet
//Then as a word is typed just use hashSet.contains() function to get if that element is there in hashSet or not [o(1) operation].
//your method can return whatever contains method returns.

Let me know if you need any more details.

-Sami